# Error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an error that I cannot figure out in Unity.

What this does (I think) is move a platform to and from points.

I have just put some text here so I can actually post this... why does stack overflow do this.

Here's the error:

> Assets\Scripts\Mover.cs(74,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour {

  public Vector3[] points;
  public int point_number = 0;
  private Vector3 current_target;

  public float tolerance;
  public float speed;
  public float delay_time;

  private float delay_start;

  public bool automatic;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
         if(points.lengh > 0)
         {
           current_target = 0;
         }
         time = speed * Time.deltaTime;
       }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(transform.position != current_target)
        {
           MovePlatform();
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateTarget();
        }
    }

    void  MovePlatform()
    {
      Vector3 heading = current_target - transform.position;
      transform.position += (heading / heading.magnitude) * speed * time.deltaTime;
       if(heading.magnitude = tolerance)
       {
        transform.position = current_target;
        delay_start = Time.time;
       }
    }
    void UpdateTarget()
    {
      if(automatic)
      {
          if(Time.time - delay_start > delay_time)
          {
           NextPlatform();
          }
       }
    }
    public void NextPlatform()
    {
        point_number ++;
        if(point_number >= points.Length)
        {
          point_number = 0;
        }
        current_target = points[point_number];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a some basic mistakes:

1. You are not defining your class inside a namespace.
2. Your methods from `Update()` to the last one are defined outside of your class scope (closing curly bracket of your class is located before `Update()`.

I cannot check if the types you are using are defined somewhere or not.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Mover
    {
        private Vector3 current_target;
        private float delay_start;

        public Vector3[] points;
        public int point_number = 0;
        public float tolerance;
        public float speed;
        public float delay_time;
        public bool automatic;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            if (points.lengh > 0)
            {
                current_target = 0;
            }
            time = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (transform.position != current_target)
            {
                MovePlatform();
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateTarget();
            }
        }

        void MovePlatform()
        {
            Vector3 heading = current_target - transform.position;
            transform.position += (heading / heading.magnitude) * speed * time.deltaTime;
            if (heading.magnitude = tolerance)
            {
                transform.position = current_target;
                delay_start = Time.time;
            }
        }
        void UpdateTarget()
        {
            if (automatic)
            {
                if (Time.time - delay_start > delay_time)
                {
                    NextPlatform();
                }
            }
        }
        public void NextPlatform()
        {
            point_number++;
            if (point_number >= points.Length)
            {
                point_number = 0;
            }
            current_target = points[point_number];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked this is in a long time. I redid the entire thing, I fixed it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an extra curley in your start function that is messing with your code

```
 void Start()
    {
         if(points.lengh > 0)
         {
            current_target = 0;
         }
         time = speed * Time.deltaTime;
       }
    }
```

— remove last curley

Answer (score 0):

the `time` Variable isn't exist

the `magnitude` Property is read-only (It means you can't set any value on magnitude)

the type of `current_target` is Vector3 so u need to set values that their Types are Vector3

there is no Property exist for Vector3 variables that called `length`

looks like you are missing one of the Brackets in the code or write wrong